# I'm getting an "Unexpected identifier" error when I try to import the "Highway" package

Tags: javascript, npm, package

I've installed [`Highway`](https://highway.js.org) using the terminal and when I run the following script:

```
import Highway from '@dogstudio/highway';
import Fade from './transition';

const H = new Highway.core({
  transition: {
    default: Fade
  }
});
```

The first line throws the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ***How*** did you install `Highway`? In other words, what command(s) did you use to install `Highway`?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code, the command is exactly "npm install --save @dogstudio/highway"

Comment: You said that you `installed by terminal`, do you mean a Visual Studio Code **terminal package**?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code, there could be several possible reasons as to why this isn't working.

#### 1. Importing the package properly:

Try changing the first two lines to this:

```
import { Highway } from '@dogstudio/highway';
import { Fade } from './transition';
```

#### 2. Installing the package properly:

Over on the [installation documentation](https://highway.js.org/installation.html) (for `Highway`) it says to install it using NPM, you'd use the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev @dogstudio/highway
```

You'd then import `Highway` as you did before, like this:

```
import Highway from '@dogstudio/highway';
```

**WARNING:** if you get a *"permissions error"* you'll have to use `sudo` (put it before `npm`) to grant your user access files/folders that require elevated privileges.

#### 3. Setting up an NPM project:

Use `npm init -y` to set up an `npm` project in your current directory, omit the `-y` option to manually make the decisions.

Good luck.

Comment: I used the command said on the highway website and your command, it says the same thing for both "+ @dogstudio/highway@2.1.2
updated 1 package and audited 2320 packages in 9.558s
found 0 vulnerabilities" and the error line line is still there

Comment: I think I might have found the problem and I've updated my answer, can you try the first suggestion? Don't hesitate to let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: In visual code, if my mouse is on the '@' of @dogstudio/highway, I see : module "d:/Projets Programmation/page-transitions-js-master/node_modules/@dogstudio/highway/build/highway"
Could not find a declaration file for module '@dogstudio/highway'. 'd:/Projets Programmation/page-transitions-js-master/node_modules/@dogstudio/highway/build/highway.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/dogstudio__highway` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@dogstudio/highway';`ts(7016)

Comment: npm install @types/dogstudio__highway I tried it but it said npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: .     So the package is installed ?

Comment: @JolHaricot Please don't post duplicate comments and no it isn't installed, edit your question then add the contents of your `package.log` file, then let me know.